# Setup env variable in aws SageMaker container (bring your own container)

Tags: aws-sdk, amazon-sagemaker

We are using aws sagemaker that is using ecs container, Is there a way, we can setup environment variable (e.g. stage or prod) in container when calling sagemaker api using low level python sdk

Answer (score 8):

Even invoking the API directly (which is lower level than using the python SDK) you cannot directly set environment arbitrary variables inside the container.  You can however pass arbitrary hyperparameters in as configuration for a TrainingJob, for example pass in a hyperparameter like `{"mystage": "prod"}`.  Hyperparameters show up in the container in a file called `/opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json` which is a simple key-value map as a JSON object.  You can use this to set the environment variable in a launching script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

export STAGE=$(jq -r ".mystage" /opt/ml/input/config/hyperparameters.json)

# Now run your code...
```

You can get SageMaker to invoke this script either by making it the `ENTRYPOINT` in your `Dockerfile`, or by calling it `train` and making sure it's on the `PATH` for the shell if you're not setting an `ENTRYPOINT`.

Comment: we ended up doing this hack only, unless find a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can configure [environment variables for an ECS Task](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task_definition_parameters.html#container_definition_environment), this is a common one to differentiate between dev/prod mode.

> environment - The environment variables to pass to a container. This
>   parameter maps to Env in the Create a container section of the Docker
>   Remote API and the --env option to docker run.

My answer isn't related Sagemaker, since I think the question refers only to ECS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the **low-level Boto SageMaker client**, it might work for you to set environment variables for your models using the `create_model` method. This method lets you define environment variables as part of the PrimaryContainer that will be available alongside the model artifacts in an instance of your container.

Source:

- https://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/sagemaker.html#SageMaker.Client.create_model

In the **high-level sagemaker Python package**, environment variables can be set as well, f.e. through the `Estimator.deploy()` and `Estimator.create_model()` methods (as additional args will be passed to `Model`).

Sources:

- http://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.deploy
- http://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/estimators.html#sagemaker.estimator.Estimator.create_model
- http://sagemaker.readthedocs.io/en/latest/model.html

**Note:** It seems that this approach is only working at inference time, not during a training job.

Answer (score 0):

An extension to @leopd 's answer is to parse the EnvVar `SM_TRAINING_ENV` that Sagemaker sets and use it directly from your Python code (`train.py`):

```
import json
import os

if __name__ == '__main__':
    envs = dict(os.environ)
    sm_training_env = envs.get('SM_TRAINING_ENV')
    sm_training_env = json.loads(sm_training_env)
    hyperparameters = sm_training_env.get('hyperparameters')
    #do_train(hyperparameters)
```

Also, just realized that the hyperparameters passed to the Estimator get set as `SM_HP_NAMEOFPARAMETER` and can be accessed directly.